# Audio player form url in html 5, hugo and netlify

Tags: html, audio, netlify, hugo

I'm trying add an audio player that stream audio from an url.
My site was created using hugo, it's running on netlify.

Here's the code.

```html
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="http://url.redacted:8386/test" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It works on localhost but when pushed to github and built on netlify, it just doesn't work. The player is greyed out.

Thank you for your help!

As seen in the box above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- audio -->
    <audio controls="controls">
      <source
        src="http://replace.with.your/audio.mp3"
        type="audio/mpeg"
      />
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save file as `index.html` and deploy your Hugo site to Netlify.
Once deployed, visit your site to see the audio player in action.

Comment: The point is, I'm not trying to play audio from an .mp3 file but from a streaming source. 

Another thing is, it's working on mobile - Safari browser - but doesn't work on desktop -  Chrome. Same code works in wordpress, and on local hugo server.